# Android gradle build speed

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

When the android project has multiple builds for prod, dev and other testing environments the build process takes long. Each build flavor is evaluated even when only one was compiled. Is there any way to exclude other builds when creating an apk of a particular flavor ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can start appropriate task. If your flavor is called **prod** than to build just prod apk you should run:

```
gradlew assembleProdRelease
```

Comment: still I see gradle is configuring dependencies for all flavors, even if I build one flavor

> Configuring > 6/7 projects > Resolving dependencies ':app:_flavorNameDebugApk'

Comment: What is in your build/outputs when build is finished?

Comment: it outputs only the flavor I specified, but while building gradle takes a lot of time "resolving" all the build flavors